# Can't resolve C warning related to pointer array in STM32CubeIDE

Tags: c, stm32, c11, stm32cubeide

Facing a a warning which we are not able to get rid of. I am using stm32 MCU and STM32CubeIDE with a standard C11 compiler.
I think I can understand why the compiler is throwing the warning but the problem is I am not able to resolve.
Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

The array of pointer is defined this way

```
static const GPIO_TypeDef *gpioOutPortss[GPIO_OUT_CH_NR] =
{
    DOUT_OD_OUT4_GPIO_Port,
    DOUT_OD_OUT6_GPIO_Port,
    DOUT_OD_OUT5_GPIO_Port,
    DOUT_OD_OUT7_GPIO_Port,
    DOUT_LED_DISABLE_GPIO_Port,
    DOUT_BUZZ_GPIO_Port,
    DOUT_OD_OUT8_GPIO_Port,
    DOUT_OD_OUT3_GPIO_Port,
    DOUT_OD_OUT2_GPIO_Port,
    DOUT_OD_OUT1_GPIO_Port,
    DOUT_ALARM_GPIO_Port,
    DOUT_12V_PWR_GPIO_Port,
    DOUT_12V_PWR_GPIO_Port
};
```

The function to be called is defined this way:

```
void HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIO_TypeDef* GPIOx, uint16_t GPIO_Pin, GPIO_PinState PinState)
{
  /* Check the parameters */
  assert_param(IS_GPIO_PIN(GPIO_Pin));
  assert_param(IS_GPIO_PIN_ACTION(PinState));

  if(PinState != GPIO_PIN_RESET)
  {
    GPIOx->BSRR = GPIO_Pin;
  }
  else
  {
    GPIOx->BSRR = (uint32_t)GPIO_Pin << 16U;
  }
}
```

The actual function call looks like this:

```
if (gpioOutPolarity[channel])
{
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(gpioOutPortss[channel], gpioOutPins[channel],
    GPIO_PIN_SET);
}
```

The warning generated by the compiler is this:

```
warning: passing argument 1 of 'HAL_GPIO_WritePin' discards 'const' qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
```

Comment: Remove the `const` if you really do want to be able to change the `gpioOutPortss` entries.

Comment: I don't think you want to change `gpioOutPortss`. Just add an explicit cast to get rid of the warning. I guess changing the declaration of `HAL_GPIO_WritePin` is not an option?

Comment: You might want to read up on the differences between const pointers and pointers to consts, such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143262/what-is-the-difference-between-const-int-const-int-const-and-int-const

Comment: @EugeneSh. `GPIOx->BSRR = GPIO_Pin;` That does seem to imply OP wants to change the entries.

Comment: @kaylum `gpioOutPortss` is an array of pointers, which are not being changed.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Right. But the `const` applies to each pointer in the array and not to the array (I think). That C syntax does seem a bit ambiguous so I could be wrong. Though that is what the warning does suggest.

Comment: @EugeneSh.  Adding a cast makes the warning go away but why make your code ugly just to cover up a mistake that you can fix?  More importantly it also wastes RAM which might not be acceptable on an embedded platform.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to write:

```
static GPIO_TypeDef * const gpioOutPortss[GPIO_OUT_CH_NR] =
```

not

```
static const GPIO_TypeDef *gpioOutPortss[GPIO_OUT_CH_NR] =
```

The GPIO blocks are not constant (otherwise you couldn't write to them), only the pointers to them are constant.

Comment: Thank you @Tom V This one did the trick!